# Ubuntu - USB device not discovered after system restart

Tags: ubuntu, usb

I have an USB device that after pluging in is visible as /dev/ttyACM0. Unfortunately, after system restart, it is not beeing discovered and I have to plug it out and in again to work. I have found a piece of code: http://www.clearchain.com/blog/posts/resetting-the-usb-bus-under-linux but it's result is similar to the system restart. If device is present and working, program sees it, claims that it is beeing reset and then device dissapear from /dev. Otherwise nothing is happenig.

My question is: How to force the system to discover my device without pluging it of and on again?

I'm Using Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 LTS.
I will appreciate any tips.

Comment: I invite you to read the following question from [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) it will help us if you [edit] your question to add   --> precise and relevant <-- information

Comment: After reading post above I still can't see what more informations I could attach to my question that could be usefull. My system configuration is default, I didn't install any fancy drivers. What happens is just after system restart, it doesn't discover device and I have to unplug i and plug again to work. 
If you can point to me what is unclear in my post or what information I could add to help you identify the problem I would happily do it.